# How do my answers to the Pokemon Trainer Test influence my starter pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

While going to Professor Bamb'o for the first time, I am prompted to take the [Pokemon Trainer Test](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Pokemon_Trainer_Test).  How do my answers to these questions affect the starter pokemon I receive?

Comment: Trainers that take the test are then sorted into one of 3 categories:

Defensive: Prefers strategies revolving in protection and healing. Gets the starter Pokemon Orchynx.
Balanced: Fights using a mix of offensive and defensive strategies. Gets the starter Pokemon Eletux.
Offensive: Uses an all-out attack strategy to crush their opponents. Gets the starter Raptorch . Source: http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Pokemon_Trainer_Test. I'm not sure yet which answers give which pokemons tho.

Answer (score 2):

According to Pokemon Uranium wikia, this is how you answers influence the starter. I don't know why there's a different number of answers listed (probably the test has changed), but I don't have the game and I can't check the actual questions.

- To get an [**Orchynx** in the Pokemon Trainer Test](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Orchynx#Trivia), answer the questions in the following way: (**Defensive**: Prefers strategies revolving in protection and healing.)

  > - Wait and See What It Does
  > - Protect
  > - Gliscor
  > - Exploring the Region
- To get a [**Raptorch** in the Pokemon Trainer Test](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Raptorch#Trivia), answer the questions in the following way: (**Offensive**: Uses an all-out attack strategy to crush their opponents)

  > - Magmar
  > - Aggressive
  > - One Hit KOer
  > - Fame and Money
  > - Hyper Beam
- To get a [**Eletux** in the Pokemon Trainer Test](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Eletux#Trivia) . To get that result, answer the questions in the following way: (**Balanced**: Fights using a mix of offensive and defensive strategies.)

  > - Magcargo
  > - Well-Mannered
  > - All-Around
  > - Become a Pokemon Master
  > - Dream Eater

Comment: FWIW, the test answers are colour coded red, green and blue. The green answers correspond to getting the grass-type, Orchynx, and so forth